# Why the object is not moving on constant speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not sure if it's got anything to this two methods but when the objectToThrow is closer to the target the speed is slower on ThrowObject and ThrowBack the speed is the same but slower when it's closer by distance to the target and if the target is far the speed of the objectToMove movement will be faster.

I want the speed to be the same if it's closer or far or at least ot be able to set the speed for closer targets and for far targets.

```
IEnumerator ThrowObject(Transform objectToMove, float duration, InteractableItem primaryTarget)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

            float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, primaryTarget.transform.position) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

            objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, primaryTarget.transform.position, time);

            yield return null;
        }

        primaryTarget.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        var naviParent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent");
        StartCoroutine(ThrowBack(objectToMove, naviParent.transform.position , duration, primaryTarget));
    }
```

And :

```
IEnumerator ThrowBack(Transform objectToMove,Vector3 originalPosition , float duration, InteractableItem primaryTarget)
{
    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

        float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, originalPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;
        objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, originalPosition, time);
        yield return null;
    }

    objectToMove.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    if (primaryTarget.name == "kid_from_space_helmet")
    {
        var helmetParent = GameObject.Find("Helmet Parent");
        GameObject Helmet = helmetParent.transform.Find("kid_from_space_helmet").gameObject;
        Helmet.SetActive(true);
    }

    IsAlreadyThrown = false;
    primaryTarget.interactableMode = InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Description;
    primaryTarget.distance = 0;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to interpolate `objectToThrow`'s position such that it reaches `primaryTarget` in `duration` seconds with no easing?

Comment: @verified_tinker Yes, objectToMove is moving fine to the primaryTarget and also moving back from the targetPrimary my problem is that if the primaryTarget is close to the objectToMove then the objectToMove will move slower very slow but if primaryTarget is far very far from the objectToMove then objectToMove will move to the primaryTarget very fast. And I want objectToMove to move the same speed no matter if primaryTarget is very close or very far.

Comment: @DanielLip right now it won't move at a constant speed because the speed is tied to the frame rate.  So  depending on how fast game loop is, will speed up/slow down your transition.

Comment: As I said in the last question you posted about this.  Your speed is stored in ```time``` and you're calculating it based on the distance it has to travel.  If you want to have a constant speed regardless of distance then you need to stop using the distance in your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you're using `Vector3.MoveTowards()`, and I definitely don't understand what you're doing with `time`. I don't have much — any — experience with it, as I favor linear interpolation, or lerping.

But I've encountered similar trouble before, so it's probably a problem with your `time`. You're modifying it each iteration because you're basing it on the distance difference, whereas the example in the docs uses a constant `speed`.

That said, instead of pointing out what's wrong with your code, it'd be easier to write down a solution I use in these cases that should work.

```
private IEnumerator Throw(Transform objectToMove, float duration, Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    float counter = 0f;
    var initialPosition = objectToMove.transform.position;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        var currentPosition = Vector3.Lerp(initialPosition, targetPosition, counter / duration);
        objectToMove.position = currentPosition;
        yield return null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

From what I've been able to understand, `MoveTowards()` is preferable when you'd like to move an object at a given speed, whereas `Lerp()` is better when it's the duration you want to control.

Additionally, for less coupling and cleaner code, I'd suggest that you chain this one coroutine twice and add the necessary code once the 2nd ("back") throw is done, like so:

```
private IEnumerator ThrowBackAndForth(Transform objectToMove, float duration, InteractableItem primaryTarget)
{
    Vector3 originalPosition = objectToMove.transform.position;
    Vector3 targetPosition = primaryTarget.transform.position;

    // Throw "forward".
    yield return StartCoroutine(Throw(objectToMove, duration, targetPosition));
    // Throw "back".
    yield return StartCoroutine(Throw(objectToMove, duration, originalPosition));

    // And then do whatever you were doing after the while loop concluded in ThrowBack().
}
```

Of course, you know your code best, so customize as needed.

Comment: The objectToMove is not moving at all now and also I notice this variable is no in use var currentPosition

Comment: My bad, I forgot to assign it! Edited.